# Cloud Print is Queing Jobs but not printing?

Tags: google-chrome, printing, google-cloud-print

I have set up Google's Cloud Print on my local PC. I added a classic printer, an HP Deskjet 845c.

I then used Cloud Print from Chrome to print a test page. However, it just queues the job and does not actually print the page. I then used my tablet to Could Print; once again it queued the job without printing.

So I now have 2 jobs waiting in the queue of my printer when I check, but the jobs are not printing.

What can I do to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Just to be sure...the cloud print connector is running when this happens?

Comment: Yes, I assume so...Chrome is running

Comment: YMMV, but here's what worked for me: access `chrome://devices` from the device you just order to print (assuming it is a desktop computer or a laptop). Then click on 'manage' next to the printer you want to print with. This should unstuck the queued jobs.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and solved it with Google's support advice. In my case, there were two printers with the same name and that caused a problem. Also, you do not note what OS you are using, but there is a requirement for Windows XP to have sp 3. I am also using Google Chrome as suggested by Google.

Their suggestions:

> Make sure your Google Cloud Print connector is running on a computer
>   that is turned on and using the latest version of Google Chrome.
>
> Make sure your printer is on and connected to the computer running the
>   Google Cloud Print connector.
>
> Make sure you're printing to the correct printer. Sometimes, there may be duplicate printers shown.
>
> In Google Chrome, select Settings and click the Show advanced settings
>   link. In the "Google Cloud Print" section, click Sign out of Google
>   Cloud Print. Visit the Google Cloud Print management page and click on
>   Printers. Delete any duplicate printers (printers with the exact same
>   name) and then sign in to Google Cloud Print again.
>
> [Source](https://support.google.com/cloudprint/?rd=1#2541920)

Comment: Os on client is Android Latest, OS on Print Server is Windows 8 64 bit